# Difference between PBE and PBKDF2 in Java

Tags: java, encryption-symmetric, jce, pbkdf2

I read in [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#SecretKeyFactory) that `SecretKeyFactory` accepts both `PBEWith...` algorithms and `PBKDF2With...` algorithms. According to PKCS #5 (current version is 2.1 specified by [RFC 8018](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8018)), PBE (Password-Based Encryption) uses PBKDF (Password-Based Key Derivation Function). Why would the generated key be different (or are they different)? Haven’t PBE covered the case for PBKDF?

Comment: Individual PBE schemes vary. Some of the PBE schemes defined in PKCS5v2+ use PBKDF1, some of them use PBKDF2, and there are also PBE schemes defined in PKCS12 which use a different PBKDF defined there (see rfc7292). Unless you specify which schemes you are interested in this Q is unanswerable.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 How do I find out which version of PBKDF1 is involved? For example, `PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_128` in Java is using HMAC and SHA-256 to derive key, but is it using PBKDF1 or PBKDF2 or something in PKCS #12 as you mentioned?

Comment: In addition, by “PBKDF defined in PKCS #12” did you mean [RFC 7292, Appendix B](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7292#appendix-B)? Since the Java documentation says that `PBEWith...` series are “secret-key factory for use with PKCS5 password-based encryption”, does it means that the PBE scheme is irrelevant to this question? (Note that the question specifically targets Java.)

Comment: There are several PBKDF's but only one PBKDF1. PBEwithHmac(any)and(any) is easy -- of those three groups only PBKDF2 uses HMAC on its hash. rfc7292 app B yes, but check the erratum on the rfc-editor website (which that ietf page links to, at the top). That Java doc is mistaken (or incomplete): the 'standard' (Sun/Oracle) provider SunJCE does implement some PKCS12 PBE schemes as well as both types (but _mostly_ PBKDF2) from PKCS5. (And Java can use other providers, which can be different.)

Comment: Then is there such PRF (Pseudo-Random Function) that `PBEWith<prf>And<encryption>` is not using the same PBKDF as `PBKDF2With<prf>`? Otherwise PBE would have covered the use case for PBKDF2, even if it also covers other cases.